# Chunk an object for every 3 keys in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, chunks

I want to chunk an associative array. Every item of the given array contains information about an employee.

Given array,

```
// given array

var arr = {
  "00B065011K": {
    "salary": "35900",
    "date": "2020-12-01"
  },
  "00B101794N": {
    "salary": "8308",
    "date": "2020-12-01"
  },
  "00C100365N": {
    "salary": "28400",
    "date": "2020-12-01"
  },
  "00D100179N": {
    "salary": "8308",
    "date": "2020-12-01"
  },
  "00D100192N": {
    "salary": "8308",
    "date": "2020-12-01"
  },
  "00E101558N": {
    "salary": "10245",
    "date": "2020-12-01"
  },
  "00F100529N": {
    "salary": "10245",
    "date": "2020-12-01",
  },
  "00F100543N": {
    "salary": "10245",
    "date": "2020-12-01"
  },
  "00G100121N": {
    "salary": "8618",
    "date": "2020-12-01"
  },
};
```

I want 3 employee information per chunk and output will be,

[image]
I have tried [Split array into chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks) but not getting the expected output.

Comment: That is not an array; JavaScript doesn't have an "associative array" type. What you've got is a plain object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is an object, not an array. You can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the keys of your object in an array, then you can use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on that array to chunk your object into an array of smaller objects (each with `chunksize` properties):

```js
var obj = {
  "00B065011K": { "salary": "35900", "date": "2020-12-01" },
  "00B101794N": { "salary": "8308", "date": "2020-12-01" },
  "00C100365N": { "salary": "28400", "date": "2020-12-01" },
  "00D100179N": { "salary": "8308", "date": "2020-12-01" },
  "00D100192N": { "salary": "8308", "date": "2020-12-01" },
  "00E101558N": { "salary": "10245", "date": "2020-12-01" },
  "00F100529N": { "salary": "10245", "date": "2020-12-01", },
  "00F100543N": { "salary": "10245", "date": "2020-12-01" },
  "00G100121N": { "salary": "8618", "date": "2020-12-01" },
};

const chunksize = 3;

const output = Object.keys(obj).reduce((c, k, i) => {
  if (i % chunksize == 0) {
    c.push(Object.fromEntries([[k, obj[k]]]));
  } else {
    c[c.length - 1][k] = obj[k];
  }
  return c;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```